# Collector App Offline Syncing issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

We are using the Collector for ArcGIS app for numerous inspections. I've been tasked to manage the GIS portion of it.

Some locations lack data service so the inspectors are using the offline mode. I have been asked to add a feature service to the map after the fact and cannot seem to get the app to pull the new feature service into the offline mode.

*Do the users have to re-download the map to access this new editable feature service?*

I was under the impression that syncing it should pull new features as well.

Comment: yes, you need to remove and re-download the map on each device. Syncing is only for the layers already on the map but if you change something in the map definition (new layers, change of style etc.) you have to re-download it every time.

Comment: Thank you! I guess we will be doing that!

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that you try the AmigoCollect app, it provides offline mode option with auto-sync once online and a plug in to sync with ArcGIS or QGis. Also, you can store offline layers that sync on all devices without having to remove and re-download the map on each device.